# Remove method for string/words

Tags: python, function, methods

I am trying to write a method for an item removal in a list based on the target value. Here goes:

```
def remove (self, target_value):
    str_list = self.str_list
    pos = 0
    for item in str_list:
        if item != target_value:
            str_list[pos] = item
            pos += 1
    del str_list[pos:]
    return str_list
```

Unfortunately this works only for a single word i.e.

if str_list = apple (it is essentially converted to a list ['a','p','p','l','e'] in my init method)

target_item = 'a'

output = pple.

What changes are needed in order to make it work for several words i.e.

if str_list = I ate an apple

target_item = ate

output = I an apple

PS: No in-built methods are allowed.

Comment: I cant use .remove() or any such inbuilt methods.

Comment: @asettouf OP said no in-built methods are allowed

Comment: Your question is not very specific: do you have to do the remove only once or more then once? Anyway, have a look at slicing and recursion.

Comment: P.S. Although I understand this is an exercise I'd consider `del` and slices also built-in methods?

Comment: how about `regex`, can we use that

Comment: If more than one instance of a target_item are found in str_list , they are to be removed. My code works only for a single word with characters but not for multiple words as in input.

Comment: @KindStranger My bad indeed, I guess an approach is to create a new list and push everything but the target value. See my answer below

Comment: I can use del() but cant use regex

Comment: do you want output in list ?

Comment: @akashkarothiya yes thats not an issue.

Comment: @phoenix If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The straightforward approach is to create an empty list, and push inside every word except the target. Return then that list:

```
def remove_token(list_val, target_val):
    size=0
    for item in list_val:
         size += 1
    str_list = [None]*size
    pos = 0
    counter_target = 0
    for item in list_val:
        if item != target_val:
            #print(pos)
            str_list[pos] = item
            pos += 1
        else:
            counter_target +=1
    return str_list[:-counter_target]
```

The below:

```
print(remove_token(["I", "ate", "an", "apple"], "ate"))
```

Gives an output:

```
['I', 'an', 'apple']
```

Note: Just to make it clear, I am using Python 3.6 (it should work for earlier version besides the `print` statement (for Python 2.x))

Comment: Can you suggest this without the len() function ?

Comment: @phoenix Sure, there you go